# How do I check if arguments are given?

Tags: discord.py

I want to check if the user has given two arguments, the first being a user to ban (mentioned) and a reason.

If a user is not mentioned, it will show a message saying "You must mention a user you'd like to ban" and if a reason isn't given, it will ban the user with the message "No Reason Given".

I'd also like to make it so you can't ban yourself, if not already implemented by discord.py

I've tried using an `if args == None:` statement, but it doesn't work.

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, arg):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Punishments", color=0x3b55e8)
    embed.add_field(name=f"{member} has been banned for:", value=arg)
    embed.set_footer(text=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.ban()
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", color=0x3b55e8)
        embed.add_field(name="You do not have permission to use this command", value="If you think this is incorrect, please contact a server administrator")
        embed.set_footer(text=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        print(f"{ctx.author} has attempted to ban a player, but does not have the correct permissions")
```

I don't receive any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for your reason, and add an error handler to handle the failure when a required argument is not passed:

```
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, arg="No Reason Given"):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Punishments", color=0x3b55e8)
    embed.add_field(name=f"{member} has been banned for:", value=arg)
    embed.set_footer(text=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await member.ban()

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", color=0x3b55e8)
        embed.add_field(name="You do not have permission to use this command", value="If you think this is incorrect, please contact a server administrator")
        embed.set_footer(text=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        print(f"{ctx.author} has attempted to ban a player, but does not have the correct permissions")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("You must mention a user you'd like to ban")
    else:
        raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick Haugh has already answered the question but best you create an error.py and insert all the global errors there.
 [Link to the documentation (CommandErrors)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.3/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions)

This can look like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Error(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=f"You don't have the permission to execute this bot command!"))
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=f"The bot command doesn't exist!"))
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=f"The command is incomplete, missing one or more parameters!"))
        if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=f"The command was entered incorrectly, one or more parameters are wrong or in the wrong place!"))


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Error(bot))
```